# is it possible to change the location of "C:\Users" to somewhere else?

Tags: rdp, windows-server-2019

I'm new to Windows Server, I'm running Windows Server 2019 and I am wondering if it is possible to change the location of "C:\Users" to a location that is on another disk
If not, what other options can I use, do I need to assign C:\Users\%username% individually or are there alternatives? I plan on using this installation of to host RDP connections and my C:\ is only a small 128GB m.2 SSD while my D:\ is capable of holding up to 4TB of data

Answer (score 0):

A common practice is to use a different file server which stores the user profiles.
You can configure this via Group Policies with the option Folder Redirections.

Microsoft has a guide about this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/folder-redirection/deploy-folder-redirection

Another option might be using `User Profile Disks`. This can be configured at the Session collection.